# Custom referenced file from launch.json for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

we have a project in which there are a number of launch/debug options referenced in the top-level Visual Studio Code's .vscode/launch.json file.

The issue is that this file needs to be edited for custom *local* debug options so it constantly triggers Git issues when doing a pull (stash etc) and at worst, sometimes gets committed with changes people needed locally. Yes, I know that's what PRs are for but somehow they keep sneaking in...

Unfortunately there are plenty of entries in the launch.json that need to be shared between devs so ignoring it is not an option.

Ideally I'd like to keep launch.json clean and have it reference another file that devs can tinker with and keep *that* one out of source.

Is there a way to do this or maybe have an approach that amounts to the same thing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

with the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you can use the command [`extension.commandvariable.file.content`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content) to read parts of a file and use it in your launch config. You can place the file in your `.vscode` directory and place that file also in your `.gitignore`.

The file can be a Key-Value text file or a JSON file.